# using a boolean condition count the months that have the condition sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

So I have a table like this:

```
---id---datetime---month---active
    1   2016-12-01  Dec-16  0
    1   2016-12-02  Dec-16  1
    1   2017-01-28  Jan-17  1
    1   2017-02-03  Feb-17  0
    1   2017-02-24  Feb-17  0
    1   2017-03-05  Mar-17  0
    1   2017-03-24  Mar-17  1
    1   2017-04-02  Apr-17  1
    1   2017-04-25  Apr-17  1
    1   2017-05-02  May-17  1
    1   2017-05-28  May-17  0
```

I would like a result like this:

```
---id---monthCount---Active
    1       1          0
    1       2          1
    1       2          0
    1       3          1
    1       1          0
```

The table does have more than 1 `id`.

Right now I'm just getting the diff between the min and max date using a partition and rank by the `id`, `active` and ordering by `datetime` but this gives me the months between when it first goes to 1 and when it finally changes to 0. I want it separated in detail by each change of `active`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql server 2012+, you could use `LAG` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    id int,
    [datetime] datetime,
    active bit
)


;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT   sd.id,
          sd.active, 
          sd.[datetime],
          lag(sd.active) over(PARTITION BY sd.id ORDER BY sd.datetime) AS previousActive,
          lag(sd.id) over( ORDER BY sd.id, sd.datetime) AS previousId
    FROM @SampleData sd
)
,temp1 AS
(
    SELECT *, 
          sum(CASE WHEN t.previousActive IS NULL OR t.previousActive != t.active OR t.id != t.previousId THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END) 
          OVER(PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.[datetime]) AS groupid
    FROM temp t
)
SELECT t.id, count(DISTINCT month(t.datetime)) AS monthCount, t.active  
FROM temp1 t
GROUP BY id, t.groupid, t.active
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/SJZ16279

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the groups using a difference of row numbers (this is a gaps-and-islands problem).  The final solution then needs `count(distinct)`:

```
select id, count(distinct month) as monthcount, active
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by month, active) as seqnum_i,
             row_number() over (partition by id, active order by month) as seqnum_ia
      from t
     ) t
group by id, active, (seqnum_i - seqnum_ia);
```

This is assuming that the data is ordered by id, month, active -- which is the ordering of the data in the question.  It really would be better to have a single column that clearly defines the sort order of the rows.

Comment: what are the parentheses? I get an error when I try to run the code because of incorrect syntax and I had never seen a grouping like that could you explain? is it a mistake?